# Different Window Minimize Behavior With Different Shells

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-7, registry

I have a kiosk-style application where the user/operator can select applciations using special keys.

I have a management application that monitors the keys (via another API) and attempts to minimize and maximize other application windows as required.

For any given application, the pseudocode looks like:

```
  foreach(var process in NotCurrentProcess())
  {
    ShowWindowAsync(process.MainWindowHandle, SW_FORCEMINIMIZE);
  }
  ShowWindowAsync(myProcess.MainWindowHandle, SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED);
```

This works fine for testing.

For deployment my application becomes the shell at `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon`

Now when I minimize an application, there's no taskbar for it to go to and it floats above the top window.

[image: Floating minimized windows]

Can anyone help with a root cause/fix for this?

Comment: Your shell needs to respond to HSHELL_GETMINRECT.

Comment: @RaymondChen Can you tell me the significance of this?

Comment: That notification controls where minimized windows are shown.

Comment: @RaymondChen Thanks for that - this approach would also have worked, at the cost of having to handle another WinApi message via P/Invoke.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you just want to hide the windows since there is no task bar to dock them in, right?

Rather than minimize the application window, just position it offscreen Like 10000 pixels to the left of where it is now using [SetWindowPos](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633545%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  Alternatively, you could just hide each window with the SW_HIDE flag to your ShowWindow call.

```
for (process in NotCurrentProcess())
{
    SetWindowPos(process.MainWindowHandle, HWND_BOTTOM, -10000, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE|SWP_NOZORDER);

    // OR call ShowWindow(process.MainWindowHandle, SW_HIDE);

}
SetWindowPos(myProcess.MainWindowHandle, HWND_TOP, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE);
ShowWindowAsync(myProcess.MainWindowHandle, SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED);
```

Comment: Thanks alot - I'd tried the `SetWindowPos` before, but didn't know about the `SWP_NOSIZE` flag of the proper use of `HWND_TOP`. Validating this approach now...

Comment: works, brilliant, thx. The only difference to the accepted answer is I use `ShowWindow` not `ShowWindowAsync` because the primary purpose of my applciation is to manage those windows and I prefer to have synchronous calls for that.